# Get UTC + 1 time with javascript

Tags: javascript, internationalization, datetime-format

```
var options = { timeZone: 'UTC', timeZoneName: 'short'};
const today = new Date();
$w("#pikoTimer").text = today.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", options);
```

This is my code i want to use, so when I click a button it sets the text to UTC time - with UTC it works fine but I want to set it to UTC + 1 and I cant find a solution.

When i try timeZone: 'UTC+1' it gives me an error saying: RangeError: Invalid time zone specified: UTC+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should specify time zone name in option's `timeZone` field like `timeZone: 'Australia/Sydney'` or `timeZone: 'EST'`; and `utc+1` is a invalid time zone name. read more in mdn [Intl/DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat); you can use a city name with the time zone you want like this:

```js
const options = { timeZone: 'Europe/London', timeZoneName: 'short'};
const today = new Date();
console.log(today.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", options))
```

Answer (score 4):

The ECMAScript Language Specification stipulates ([ECMA-262 section 20.4.4.40](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring)) that the `options` parameter of the [`Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) function is to be implemented *as specified in [ECMA-402](https://tc39.es/ecma402/)* (the ECMAScript Internationalization API Specification).

According to ECMA-402, the `timeZone` option is valid if it conforms to [section 6.4](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-time-zone-names) (“Time Zone Names”), which stipulates:

> The ECMAScript […] Internationalization API Specification identifies time zones using the Zone and Link names of the IANA Time Zone Database. Their canonical form is the corresponding Zone name in the casing used in the IANA Time Zone Database.

Which is why your code works when using `UTC` (which is a link to `Etc/UTC` in the [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)), but you get an error when using `UTC+1` (which is not a valid IANA Time Zone).

Instead, you should use a value that represents the same [UTC+01:00 offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B01:00), and observes desired daylight time adjustments. For example, you may use `Europe/Paris` or `Europe/Belgrade`.

```
const options = { timeZone: 'Europe/Paris', timeZoneName: 'short'};
const today = new Date();
$w("#pikoTimer").text = today.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", options);
```

See [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for a handy online reference.